# Access VBA code execution stop and restart after specific interval

Tags: ms-access, vba

At present,I am running Access VBA for url navigation.Now i want to stop VBA after some time and then restart after some time.
ie. Want to stop on
First VBA start time + 4 hours
and then want to restart VBA on
VBA stop time + 5 minutes.

Basically i want to stop VBA after every four hours and then restart VBA after 5 minutes time interval.i.e i want to start and stop execute below mentioned code after 4 hours and then restart after 5 minutes..Thanks.

```
Private Sub getdata()

 Dim Ie As New InternetExplorer
 Dim WebURL
 Dim Docx As HTMLDocument
 Dim productDesc
 Dim productTitle
 Dim price
 Dim RcdNum

Ie.Visible = False


WebURL = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Polarized-sunglasses-Mens-Driving-glasses-Aviator-outdoor-Sports-UV400-Eyewear-/252063564211?var=&hash=item3ab028c1b3:m:mYPFr4la1j-kJkrA9w_oxDw"
 Ie.Navigate2 WebURL
 Do Until Ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 DoEvents
 Loop
 Set Docx = Ie.Document

 productDesc1 = Docx.getElementsBytagName("title")

End Sub
```

Comment: Without your code, I can only suggest to use the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Now please check code.I want o stop execution of above code after four hours and then restart after 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

To start at specific time you should schedule your process to run at a specific time. use `Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:00:00"), "MyMacro"`

as in http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/71210-schedule-vba-macro-run-specific-time.html

And to stop just create and if clause that check what time it currently is.

Comment: `Application.OnTime` only exists in Excel, not in Access.

Comment: Is there any alternate in MS Access VBA?

Comment: Is there any alternate for Application.OnTime in MS Access VBA?